# Django get related info from Many to Many through table

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have something similar to the following model

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField(...)

class Event(Model):
    event_name = CharField(...)
    event_rating = IntegerField
    users = ManyToManyField(User, through="UserEventAttendence")

class UserEventAttendence(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    event = ForeignKey(Event)
    attended = BooleanField()

class EventComments(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    content = CharField(...)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='eventcomments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my view I am trying to get all events, the users for each event, then from this filter out events that the current user is going to. Below is my current query (goes to a serializer afterwards and is then sent as a response)

```
events = models.Event.objects.using(db_to_use).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('users', queryset=models.UserProfile.objects.using(db_to_use))
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('eventcomments', queryset=models.EventComments.objects.using(db_to_use))
        ).filter(usereventattendence__user_id=request.user.id)
```

But I need to somehow append the "attended" field from the "UserEventAttendence" model for each event (for the current user), but I don't have any clue how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to get the attendence independently and build a list of tuples:

```
events_list = []
for event in events:
    attended = event.usereventattendence_set.filter(user=request.user).attended
    event_list.append((event, attended))
```

Then you can iterate:

```
for event, attended in event_list:
    # do stuff
```

Or pass as context to the template processor.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I had to get it independently and not within the initial query, I used a different method to get the data, but it definitely answered my question

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value of `attended` as an annotation on `Event` objects:

```
# events is your queryset as defined in the question
# I'm not entirely sure if the field name should be 
# 'usereventattendence__attended'
# or 
# 'user_event_attendence__attended'
events.annotate(attended=F('usereventattendence__attended'))
```

You can then access `attended` on the individual events:

```
for e in events:
    print(e.attended)
```

One note on your intermediate model. It doesn't define unique constraints, which means that theoretically at least you could have several records for the same event-user pair (leading to duplicate `Event` objects in your query). If this is not desired, you would want to define a `unique_together` constraint on the intermediate model.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I get an error saying object has no attribute 'attended'

Comment: Did you perform the annotation? `events.annotate(attended=F('usereventattendence__attended'))`

Comment: To reiterate, this definitely works if you do it correctly.